# Is there a common method to password protect registration pages?

Tags: users

The site I am working on requires that affiliates register on the site. I've created a profile type for affiliates with corresponding permissions and a registration page. I'd like to give access to this and the site's main registration pages without having to deal with all the spam account registration attempts. Is there a standard way of allowing only users that you want to register to have access to registration pages?

Answer (score 0):

Well, till they register/login, you can't actually say who they are.

I will suggest a CAPTCHA in the registration form. If you want to restrict it more, then you can search for email white listing modules. https://drupal.org/sandbox/amrit_b/1768342 This is something I wrote few months back. This is still in dev. In case you don't find anything else, you can try this one.